# Combining values from multiple radio groups to show a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-group

I have three radio groups.  I would like the user to select from each group and depending on what selections show a specific div.  I'm having trouble combining the values with an && operator.  It will work as it is now, but it depends on the last value only.  So if click one of the radio buttons on the last group it will show an option which isn't good, obviously.  I'm sure there's a much better way to go about this, but this is what I've got.

I'm using jQuery 3+ but am open to whatever is easiest.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Hide the divs
    $(".w-ln-rn,.w-lsp-rsp,.b-ln-rn,.b-lsp-rsp,.message").hide();

    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {

        switch ($(this).val()) {

        case ( 'white' && 'ln' && 'rn' ):

            $(".w-ln-rn").show();
            break;

        case ( 'black' && 'lsp' && 'rsp' ):

            $(".b-lsp-rsp").show();
            break;

        case ('white' && 'lsp' && 'rsp'):

            $(".w-lsp-rsp").show();
            break;

        default:
         $(".w-ln-rn,.w-lsp-rsp,.b-ln-rn,.b-lsp-rsp,.message").hide();
    }

});

$('#reset').on('click', function() {
    $(".first,.second,.third,.message").hide();
    $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', function () {
        return this.getAttribute('checked') == 'checked';

    });
 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lsvl_co/3p08r6b5/67/

Ideally I would like to simply show a div that applies to the various options selected from the radio groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would put all the values into an array.

```
var t = []
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() {
  t.push($(this).val())
});
```

then add `t.join(' ')` to your switch `switch (t.join(' ')) {` and then your case would look like `case ('white ln rn'):`

**Working demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".w-ln-rn,.w-lsp-rsp,.b-ln-rn,.b-lsp-rsp,.message").hide();

  /* $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false); */

  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    var t = []
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() {
      t.push($(this).val())
    });
    switch (t.join(' ')) {

      case ('white ln rn'):

        $(".w-ln-rn").show();
        break;

      case ('black lsp rsp'):

        $(".b-lsp-rsp").show();
        break;

      case ('white lsp rsp'):

        $(".w-lsp-rsp").show();
        break;

      default:
        $(".w-ln-rn,.w-lsp-rsp,.b-ln-rn,.b-lsp-rsp,.message").hide();
    }


    /* if ( $("input[value='white']").is(':checked') && $("input[value='rsp']").is(':checked') ) {
                $(".first").show();
             } elseif ($("input[value='black']").is(':checked') && $("input[value='rn']").is(':checked')); {
                 $(".second").show();
             } */



  });

  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    $(".first,.second,.third,.message").hide();
    $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', function() {
      return this.getAttribute('checked') == 'checked';

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> Unit Color </h2>

<input type="radio" value="white" name="unit" />White
<input type="radio" value="black" name="unit" />Black
<br/>

<h2> Left Handle </h2>
<input type="radio" value="ln" name="left" />Normal
<input type="radio" value="lsp" name="left" />Super Plush


<h2> Right Handle </h2>
<input type="radio" value="rn" name="right" />Normal
<input type="radio" value="rsp" name="right" />Super Plush


<div class="message">
  <h2>Please select an option!</h2>
</div>

<div class="w-ln-rn">White / Left Normal / Right Normal</div>
<div class="w-lsp-rsp">White / Left Super Plush / Right Super Plush</div>
<div class="b-ln-rn">Black / Left Normal / Right Normal</div>
<div class="b-lsp-rsp">Black / Left Super Plush / Right Super Plush</div>

<br><br>

<div id="reset-btn">
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Carsten, one issue is that when you switch options, it doesn't always remove the show (display:block).  So if you choose three selections, then choose another, it doesn't always remove the display:block from the item that is no longer selected.  Not sure the if an if/else statement would resolve that?

Comment: @justiny It does on mine but you can move the `$(".w-ln-rn,.w-lsp-rsp,.b-ln-rn,.b-lsp-rsp,.message").hide()` before the switch statement